# Какие существуют техники уменьшения потребления памяти

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Пусть есть некоторые значения о которых известно только то, что они `<= 10^6`. 
Принимая во внимание этот факт - берём массив c int ами и храним. Но как быть если не хочется использовать лишние байты (пусть `sizeof(int) == 4`) типа `int` - тоесть в данном случае можно обойтись и 3 байтами, так как `10^6 < 2^24`. Как такое реализовать ??

Comment: В это мире люди не производят процессоров с 20 битными регистрами. Хотя можно попробовать упаковку 3 значений битовыми сдвигами и маской в один 64 битный регистр. Но там все равно останется 4 бита лишних, которые будут тормозить всю систему.

Comment: Значит заведите char* массив, по 3 байта берите и приводите их к int

Comment: Хотя на самом деле есть еще один изощренный вариант в котором все выровненно. Можно хранить первые старшие 16 бит первых четырех чисел в 64 битном регистре и оставшиеся в 4 бита четырех чисел в 16 битном. Но это все означает сильную головную боль с упаковкой и распаковкой.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский а можно подробней про "берите по 3 байта" ??

Comment: @arammis http://stackoverflow.com/a/2682737/4569791

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хранение `N` 24 битовых целых можно организовать в банальном массиве `unsigned char data[N * 3]` (подразумевая 8-битный `unsigned char`).

Чтение числа с индексом `i` из массива делается просто как

```
unsigned value = 0;
memcpy(&value, &data[i * 3], 3);
```

а запись как

```
memcpy(&data[i * 3], &value, 3);
```

Для того, чтобы поддержать знаковые числа в формате 2's-compliment, если это нужно, придется сделать еще расширение знака при чтении и все. (Т.е. размножить старший бит 3-го по значимости байта на весь старший по значимости байт.)

Вышеприведенные копирования специфичны для little-endian платформ, и для big-endian платформ будут несколько иными.

Comment: будет работать только для little-endian машин (напр. с проц. Intel), но не для big-endian (напр. SPARC), так что для portability лучше использовать что-то вроде value = (((int)data[i*3+2]) << 16) | (((int)data[i*3 + 1]) << 8) | ((int)data[i*3])

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, вы храните по три байта на индекс и преобразуете индексы сами.

```
struct Int24Container
{
    int8_t* payload;
    size_t size;
};

int24c_init(Int24Container* cont, size_t size)
{
    cont->payload = (int8_t*)malloc(3 * size);
    cont->size = size;
}

int24c_destroy(Int24Container* cont)
{
    delete cont->payload;
}

int32_t in24c_get(Int24Container* cont, size_t idx)
{
    return cont -> payload[idx] |
          (cont -> payload[idx + 1] <<  8) |
          (cont -> payload[idx + 2] << 16);
}

void in24c_set(Int24Container* cont, size_t idx, int32_t x)
{
    cont -> payload[idx] =      x        & 0xff;
    cont -> payload[idx + 1] = (x >>  8) & 0xff;
    cont -> payload[idx + 2] = (x >> 16) & 0xff;
}
```

Если хотите в стиле C++, можно сделать так, как делает [`vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool).

```
class Int24Container
{
    vector<int8_t> payload;

public:
    Int24Container(size_t size) : payload(size * 3) { }

    class reference
    {
        Int24Container& cont;
        size_t idx;
    public:
        reference(Int24Container& cont, size_t idx) : cont(cont), idx(idx) {}
        reference(const reference& ref) : cont(ref.cont), idx(ref.idx) {}
        reference& operator = (int x)
        {
            cont.payload[idx] =      x        & 0xff;
            cont.payload[idx + 1] = (x >>  8) & 0xff;
            cont.payload[idx + 2] = (x >> 16) & 0xff;
            return *this;
        }
        reference& operator = (const reference& ref)
        {
            cont.payload[idx] = ref.cont.payload[idx];
            cont.payload[idx + 1] = ref.cont.payload[idx + 1];
            cont.payload[idx + 2] = ref.cont.payload[idx + 2];
            return *this;
        }
        operator int() const
        {
            return cont.payload[idx] |
                   (cont.payload[idx + 1] <<  8) |
                   (cont.payload[idx + 2] << 16);
        }
    };

    reference operator[] (int index)
    {
        return reference(*this, index * 3);
    }
};
```

---

Вместо побайтового копирования стоит попробовать использовать `memcpy`, это может оказаться быстрее.